# how to add another listening port to the nginx ingress controller kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

by default, nginx ingress listens to two ports 80 and 443, how to add listening on port 9898
I tried to change it in daemon set, but nothing came out
, I don 't even know where else to dig

Comment: Please improve your question by adding as much details as you can along with some supporting YAML code and screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what will work exactly for you, but here's a few things you can try to approach this (read carefully because nginx is confusing):

1. Define `service` for your deployment, and make sure it covers port routes you want and support on deployment end:

   ```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: web-app
      namespace: web
      labels:
        app: web-app
    spec:
      ports:
      - port: 80
        targetPort: 1337
        protocol: TCP
      selector:
        app: web-app
   ```
2. Refer to it in nginx ingress:

   ```
    rules:
    - host: mycoolwebapp.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: web-app
              port:
                number: 80
   ```

The catch here is that you can route **ALL** services via port 80 but use any target port you want, so that you can, say, add 50 ingress hosts/routes over a morning routing to port 80 and only difference they'll have is target port in `service`.
3. If you are specifically unhappy with ports 80 and 443, you are welcome to edit `ingress-nginx-controller` (`service` one, because as I said nginx is confusing).
4. Alternatively, you can find example of `ingress-nginx-controller` *service* on the web, customize it and apply, then connect `ingress` to it... but I advise against this because if nginx doesn't like anything you set up as custom service, it's easier to just reinstall whole helm release of it and try again.

Comment: unfortunately, our customers are used to handling the port and do not want without. Such requirements. that is, you need to do test.com:8080 via ingress

Comment: You didn't mention this initially, and 8080 isn't 9898, so.... port 80 is only different that it's implicit by default, so you can use test.com:80 explicitly just fine